# How to avoid Vue.JS/Axion returning undefined whereas response code is 200?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very simple Vue.JS / Axion Get request to fetch data from an API. When i debug the response it returns a 200 status code and the array/object expected.

But Vue.JS itself returns `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: response is not defined"`
why I cannot use the data.

Why is that?

**My Javascript code:**

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app_name',
    data() {
      return {
        info: null
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      axios
        .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagueTable/" + league_id)
        .then((response)=> {
                   this.info = response;
                  console.log(response);
                });
    }
    }
```

**The html part**

```
          <div class="table">
            <div><p>Team</p></div>
            <div id="app_name"><p>{{ info }}</p></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add console.log inside then function after getting response

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app_name',
  data: {
    info: null
  },
   mounted(){
    let league_id=2;
    axios
        .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/leagueTable/" + league_id)
        .then((response)=> {
           this.info = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);  
        });
       
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>



  <div class="table">
   <div><p>Team</p></div>
   
   <div id="app_name">
   <p>{{ info }}</p>
   </div>
```

you can get your data in `response.data`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now the error is gone but then I have an empty array in return.

Comment: Will do, but I have an empty response now, why is that?

Comment: please paste your updated code , so i can see what is the issue you are facing

Comment: Done, especially see the images attached for further pointing

Comment: check `response.data`

Comment: the photo you have posted is the whole response you getting , we need only `response.data`

Comment: console.log(response.data) returns `{__ob__: Observer}
api: (...)
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get api: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set api: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object`